# MySQL DATE_ADD function; how to use another value of another column as date argument on table creation

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, dateadd

I have a table for doing s.th with weeks, I want the `end` column to automatically set its value 6 days after the `start` column but I don't know how to refer to `start`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `weeks`(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `start` DATE UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    `end` DATE UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL 6 DAY), -- this line
    `availablity` INT NOT NULL
);
```

could anyone help ?

Comment: what you are doing works in mariadb but not yet in mysql.  in mysql you can use a trigger for this.

Comment: why are start and end UNIQUE?  I have trouble coming up with any good reason to do that

Answer (score 1):

you have the wrong SYNTAX

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `weeks`(
>     `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>     `start` DATE UNIQUE NOT NULL,
>     `end` DATE   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL 6 DAY)) UNIQUE,
>     `end2` DATE  NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT  (DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL 6 DAY)) ,
>     `availablity` INT NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO weeks (`start`,`availablity`) VALUEs (NOW(),1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROm weeks
> ```
>
> ```
> id | start      | end        | end2       | availablity
> -: | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | ----------:
>  1 | 2021-06-25 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-01 |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92c48a7033a2e12ec60c364e674447d3)*